# In Haskell, what could `this@(Sentence string _) = do` mean?

Tags: haskell

This is portion of a Haskell program I've been assigned to debug:

```
process :: Sentence -> IO ()
process this@(Sentence string _) = do
  render string
  render "==>"
  render $ translate this

render = putStrLn

data Sentence = Sentence String Task

translate :: Sentence -> String     ; Incomplete Definition
translate (Sentence string task)
  | ...

  | ...

  | ...

  | ...
```

The only portion of this program I don't understand or recognize is the line `process this@(Sentence string _) = do` 
I've never seen `this@` before and I'm also not so sure what the underscore in `(Sentence string _)` means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `this@` is an example of an 'as-pattern', whereas `_` is an example of a wild-card pattern. A wild-card pattern is used when we don't care what value is at that point in the pattern, so `_` in a pattern will match with anything, and it doesn't bind any local names/variables.

On the other hand, we use an as pattern when we want to bind an extra local name/variable while also matching against it. You could consider that

```
process this@(Sentence string _) = ...
```

Is roughly equivalent to

```
process this = let (Sentence string _) = this
               in ...
```

It binds the extra name given on the left of the `@` sign to the value of whatever it is matching. The at pattern itself matches everything, but the inner pattern on the right hand side of the `@` sign is also matched against whatever it is matching - and that pattern may well not match everything, in this case it matches only a `Sentence` constructor.

Because of this, the at pattern version and the version with the let binding have different behaviour if the pattern match in the let binding can fail, so the at pattern is often preferred when we are defining multiple cases for a function, as it allows the inner pattern to also affect which case of the function is called. For example

```
safeHead xs = let (x:_) = xs in Just x
safeHead [] = Nothing
```

Will fail when called with `[]`, as the pattern match of `xs` for the first argument succeeds, so the first case of the function is called, and then `xs` cannot be matched against `(x:_)`. However, if we wrote this with an as pattern:

```
safeHead xs@(x:_) = Just x
safeHead [] = Nothing
```

Calling with `[]` will work fine, because the inner pattern is also checked before we decide to use the first case of the function, and so although `xs` matches against `[]`, `(x:_)` is also matched against `[]`, which fails, and so the second case is then called. I realise this is quite a silly example, especially as we don't use xs the second time round, but I hope it illustrates the difference.

Comment: Are you saying I need to add a condition after the this@ statement to catch non-matching input?

Comment: Note this is traditionally called an "as-pattern" but the idea that some people call it an "at-pattern" isn't surprising.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson You're absolutely right, and I really should have known given how many times I've stared at the AST nodes for patterns :P

Comment: @Imray Not really no - what I'm saying is that the as pattern allows you to bind a name to a value, and also pattern match against that value. In terms of what names are bound, this is similar to just pattern matching the name, and then let or case matching the pattern. However, the whole as pattern `this@(Sentence string _)` will fail to match (and a different case is used) if any part (notably the part to the right of the `@` does not match). This is not the same as binding the name `this` and then matching `(Sentence string _)` separately.

Answer (score 4):

The `@` defines an [as pattern](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) which allows you to name the thing being matched. In this case `this` is the name given to the `Sentence` value you're matching.

Answer (score 4):

`Sentence` being a constructor that takes a `String` and a `Task`, in the pattern `this@(Sentence string _)`, `this` is an [as pattern](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions) that names the whole Sentence, `string` names the Sentence's `String`, and the underscore goes where the `Task` would otherwise be named, essentially saying the `Task` should be ignored there.

Comment: Having read the whole article, there was only silly and non-exhaustive description of what the @ symbol means. Could you add a simple but more conclusive example to your answer?