# Syntax What does @ in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, operator-keyword, function

I am new in Haskell, I noticed @ has specific role when I was reading a code, someone knows what does exactly do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Haskell, what could \`this@(Sentence string \_) = do\` mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278980/in-haskell-what-could-thissentence-string-do-mean)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@ is used in pattern matching for keeping the binding to the whole thing.

Example:

In `x@(a:as)`, `x` will refer to the entire list `a:as`.

In the above example, you can get the whole list via `x` instead of typing yourself `a:as` again.