# How do I correct a pattern binding error in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a line of code where I'm trying to assign a variable (I know haskell doesn't really have variables, but I'm not sure what else to call it) with the minimum element found by using the minimumBy builtin, but I get the following error:

```
Illegal type signature: `(x', y', z')'
      Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables
   |
   |     ed1 :: (x', y', z') = minimumBy (comparing (\(_, _, z) -> z)) e
```

Here is the code.

```
alg' pr pq nE (G c d) = alg' (ve1 : pr) (ed1 : pq) (nE - 1) (G c d)
    where
   
    e = -- helper function that compiles, but with a wrong value so I omitted it.

    ed1 :: (x', y', z') = minimumBy (comparing (\(_, _, z) -> z)) e
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `ScopedTypeVariables` like the error message says?

Comment: I have tried googling how to do that, but I didn't see much that helped me.

Comment: I have also tried 
```
(x', y', z') : ed1 = minimumBy (comparing (\(_, _, z) -> z)) e
```

Comment: That comment didn't really work out as intended...

Comment: It might be helpful, in suggesting a good answer, to see a bit more of the context in which you are using this particular line

Comment: Okay, I added the rest of that segment.

Comment: does `alg'` have a type declaration? Is it where x', y', z' appear?

Comment: Btw, `ed1 :: (x', y', z')` is not really a pattern binding, It's simply a binding with ed1 being declared to be of type `(x', y', z').

Comment: Do you mind sharing the entire `alg'`?

Comment: That's honestly all I have so far.
I updated to show what it should look like if I can figure out 'e'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `x'`, `y'`, `z'` variables are declared in the outer scope, you need to enable the `ScopedTypeVariables` annotations. You didn't specify the type signature of the enclosing `alg'` function in your question, so we'll just pretend it looks like this for the moment.

```
alg' :: (x', y', z') -> (x', y', z')
alg' (x, y, z) = (x, y, z)
    where ed1 = (x, y, z)
```

If we want to give `ed1` an explicit type signature, it needs to know about the type variables from the outer scope. To this end, we first need to enable a compiler extension. This line needs to be at the very top of your file.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

Second, we need to clarify to the compiler that we *intend* these variables be scoped, as follows.

```
alg' :: forall x' y' z'. (x', y', z') -> (x', y', z')
alg' (x, y, z) = (x, y, z)
    where ed1 :: (x', y', z')
          ed1 = (x, y, z)
```

You needn't use `forall` everywhere, even with `ScopedTypeVariables` on, but you must use it for any variables you intend to use in an inner scope.

Also, as a general piece of advice, `forall` is unfortunately an overloaded keyword and is used to mean three different things in `ScopedTypeVariables`, `RankNTypes`, and `ExistentialQuantification`. So if you happen to see `forall` in the wild, be sure to check what extensions are enabled on that file, as it could be doing something different in that case.

Comment: I don't know how you answered my question now that I see how poorly I worded it, but you did. Thank you very much

Comment: I was going to give the same answer but I wasn't sure if you want to pattern match against the tuple or declare it's type. Glad you got your solution and bit more knowledge on Haskell.

Comment: On the subject of pattern binding, what does this mean in basic haskell code?
prod @ (p', q', r')

Comment: @winnie33: It’s called an “‘as’ pattern”. See [What does the “@” symbol mean in reference to lists in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1153465/246886) and [In Haskell, what could `this@(Sentence string _) = do` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15278980/246886)—the [Haskell Report §3.17.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17) explains that `name@pattern` means: match `pattern` and also assign the whole match to `name`. If you don’t know some syntax, the Report is a good place to check first, since it defines the base language.